# What is the noun form of "disturb"?

Tags: word-choice

People sometimes say:

> Sorry for any inconvenience this caused.

Is it possible to say:

> Sorry for any disturb this caused.

when I ask for a stranger for help by email?

Updated with more context:

I wanted to ask him do me a favor, but he hasn't replied for many days. I just need his help and since it's all about business, I decided to increase my bid (pay him more money) to negotiate again. And this is the email I am writing to do so.

Comment: _Sorry to disturb you_ would work. _Sorry to inconvenience you_ could work, too, because _inconvenience_ can function as [both a noun and a verb](http://www.onelook.com/?w=inconvenience&ls=a). In any case, I think it's best to avoid that noun form in this case, as @Maurice said in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, if you're sending a follow up, especially on a request or a bid, the most common way to express yourself is to say: "Sorry to bother you, but" and then continue on with your inquiry.

And as Maulik V has noted, the noun for disturb is disturbance.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

The noun of 'disturb' is 'disturber' *(out of this context though)* or 'disturbance'

So,

> Sorry for any disturbance it caused

However, the context wherein you are asking a stranger for some help, there could be better options. And for this, *more context* is required.

But to address the main question, the noun of disturb, in such scene, is disturbance.

Comment: Note that *disturber* is a rare word.  [*Disturbance* is over a hundred times more common.](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=35539653)